# How can I save or extract my machine learning model developed in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, machine-learning-model

So I have built my machine learning prediction model in Azure ML Studio. I want to use that model for my Web App where I will be using Flask & Heroku for development purpose.

Comment: How did you build your model? With AutoML, Designer, in a Python notebook?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Machine Learning studio(Classic), Models can be trained, scored, saved, and run in AzureML studio, but can't downloaded to your local machine. There's no way to do anything with a model outside of AzureML.

As this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-pytorch

"You can also download a local copy of the model by using the Run object. In the training script pytorch_train.py, a PyTorch save object persists the model to a local folder (local to the compute target). You can use the Run object to download a copy."

```
# Create a model folder in the current directory
os.makedirs('./model', exist_ok=True)

# Download the model from run history
run.download_file(name='outputs/model.pt',
output_file_path='./model/model.pt')
```

This is available for different frameworks as well, please check the document for more details and options.